# How to add a column from a subsetted dataframe to the original dataframe in R?

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, subset

I want to add one column from a dataframe (which is a subset of anther dataframe) into the original dataframe. (I had to use the subset for another analysis). Please consider this example:

```
origdata <- data.frame(id=c(1:5), val=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
subdata <- origdata[origdata$id>3, ]
subdata$newvar <- factor(c(1, 2), levels=c(1, 2), labels=c("one", "two")) 
### Value for newvar derived from other analysis
```

Now I want to add the column containing `newvar` to the original dataframe and fill in `NA`s for all cases which were not part of the subset. My first idea was to use

```
origdata[origdata$id>3, ]$newvar <- subdata$newvar
```

which obviously does not work. Though, if I first define `newvar` as `NA` it works but I lose the all additional information gained by specifying it as a factor (as above):

```
origdata$newvar <- NA
origdata[origdata$id>3, ]$newvar <- subdata$newvar
```

Do you know an easy work-around for this? If possible, I do NOT want to use `merge` because I have large dataframes and `merge` is very time-consuming. Also, I want to keep `newvar` as a factor.

Comment: So to clarify, you've already tried `merge`, it does what you want, but you are looking for another alternative?

Comment: Yes, I tried `merge` which works, but it takes an unreasonable amount of time.

Comment: If speed is an issue,  have you tried converting to `data.table`s, setting the key to the first two columns, and then merging?

Comment: No, I have not used `data.table` so far. It looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should work

```
origdata$newvar<-subdata[match(origdata$id,subdata$id),"newvar"]
```

Comment: You are right `subset` is a mistakable name for a dataframe. I changed this in the original question.